# bm.el is broken

Tags: emacs, bookmarks, emacs23

Is anyone using bm.el to traverse through bookmarks in multiple buffers ?
If so did you notice that bm-next is broken ? I see several people using it
but no one seems to have noticed this. The buggy version
got into emacs-goodies as well. How do I go about debugging this ?

Answer (score 0):

I just install bm-1.43.el file from http://www.nongnu.org/bm/ in Ubuntu 10.04 with Emacs 23.1.1 and it seems to be working fine.

You do have to use `M-x bm-toggle-cycle-all-buffers` to set it so that `bm-next` goes through all buffers.  I haven't decided if I like that new feature yet so I'm leaving it off for now.

Answer (score 0):

*An alternative:* [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus). Includes very similar bookmark defining, highlighting, and cycling, but the bookmarks are compatible with conventional Emacs bookmarks.